# I need to create a custom script to show specific columns based on choices from a dropdown in GSheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm setting up a product tool in a google sheet, and the purpose is to only show up to 8 of about 91 columns. Each column is a product, each row is the "entitlements" or features of that product.

The sheet gives users the ability to pick from a dropdown (data validation) from the list of 91 products - up to 8 times. I'd like to then have users click 'compare' and it only shows those specific 8 products (columns) shown in the sheet.

I've written script to create a menu and automatically hide all columns on open. Where do I go from here to tie a 'Compare' button on the sheet to take all values chosen by the user, match them up to the right columns, and then show those columns?

```
function onOpen() {
  var menu = [{name: "Hide all Products", functionName: "hideAllColumns"}, {name: "Show all products", functionName: "showAllColumns"}]
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Product Tool", menu);
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  hideAllColumns();
}

function showAllColumns() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.showColumns(2);
  sheet.showColumns(3);
  sheet.showColumns(4);
  sheet.showColumns(5);
  sheet.showColumns(6);
  sheet.showColumns(7);
  sheet.showColumns(8);
  sheet.showColumns(9);
  sheet.showColumns(10);
  sheet.showColumns(11);
  sheet.showColumns(12);
  sheet.showColumns(13);
  sheet.showColumns(14);
  sheet.showColumns(15);
  sheet.showColumns(16);
  sheet.showColumns(17);
  sheet.showColumns(18);
  sheet.showColumns(19);
  sheet.showColumns(20);
  sheet.showColumns(21);
  sheet.showColumns(22);
  sheet.showColumns(23);
  sheet.showColumns(24);
  sheet.showColumns(25);
  sheet.showColumns(26);
  sheet.showColumns(27);
  sheet.showColumns(28);
  sheet.showColumns(29);
  sheet.showColumns(30);
  sheet.showColumns(31);
  sheet.showColumns(32);
  sheet.showColumns(33);
  sheet.showColumns(34);
  sheet.showColumns(35);
  sheet.showColumns(36);
  sheet.showColumns(37);
  sheet.showColumns(38);
  sheet.showColumns(39);
  sheet.showColumns(40);
  sheet.showColumns(41);
  sheet.showColumns(42);
  sheet.showColumns(43);
  sheet.showColumns(44);
  sheet.showColumns(45);
  sheet.showColumns(46);
  sheet.showColumns(47);
  sheet.showColumns(48);
  sheet.showColumns(49);
  sheet.showColumns(50);
  sheet.showColumns(51);
  sheet.showColumns(52);
  sheet.showColumns(53);
  sheet.showColumns(54);
  sheet.showColumns(55);
  sheet.showColumns(56);
  sheet.showColumns(57);
  sheet.showColumns(58);
  sheet.showColumns(59);
  sheet.showColumns(60);
  sheet.showColumns(61);
  sheet.showColumns(62);
  sheet.showColumns(63);
  sheet.showColumns(64);
  sheet.showColumns(65);
  sheet.showColumns(66);
  sheet.showColumns(67);
  sheet.showColumns(68);
  sheet.showColumns(69);
  sheet.showColumns(70);
  sheet.showColumns(71);
  sheet.showColumns(72);
  sheet.showColumns(73);
  sheet.showColumns(74);
  sheet.showColumns(75);
  sheet.showColumns(76);
  sheet.showColumns(77);
  sheet.showColumns(78);
  sheet.showColumns(79);
  sheet.showColumns(80);
  sheet.showColumns(81);
  sheet.showColumns(82);
  sheet.showColumns(83);
  sheet.showColumns(84);
  sheet.showColumns(85);
  sheet.showColumns(86);
  sheet.showColumns(87);
  sheet.showColumns(88);
  sheet.showColumns(89);
  sheet.showColumns(90);
  sheet.showColumns(91);
  sheet.showColumns(92);
}

function hideAllColumns() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.hideColumns(2);
  sheet.hideColumns(3);
  sheet.hideColumns(4);
  sheet.hideColumns(5);
  sheet.hideColumns(6);
  sheet.hideColumns(7);
  sheet.hideColumns(8);
  sheet.hideColumns(9);
  sheet.hideColumns(10);
  sheet.hideColumns(11);
  sheet.hideColumns(12);
  sheet.hideColumns(13);
  sheet.hideColumns(14);
  sheet.hideColumns(15);
  sheet.hideColumns(16);
  sheet.hideColumns(17);
  sheet.hideColumns(18);
  sheet.hideColumns(19);
  sheet.hideColumns(20);
  sheet.hideColumns(21);
  sheet.hideColumns(22);
  sheet.hideColumns(23);
  sheet.hideColumns(24);
  sheet.hideColumns(25);
  sheet.hideColumns(26);
  sheet.hideColumns(27);
  sheet.hideColumns(28);
  sheet.hideColumns(29);
  sheet.hideColumns(30);
  sheet.hideColumns(31);
  sheet.hideColumns(32);
  sheet.hideColumns(33);
  sheet.hideColumns(34);
  sheet.hideColumns(35);
  sheet.hideColumns(36);
  sheet.hideColumns(37);
  sheet.hideColumns(38);
  sheet.hideColumns(39);
  sheet.hideColumns(40);
  sheet.hideColumns(41);
  sheet.hideColumns(42);
  sheet.hideColumns(43);
  sheet.hideColumns(44);
  sheet.hideColumns(45);
  sheet.hideColumns(46);
  sheet.hideColumns(47);
  sheet.hideColumns(48);
  sheet.hideColumns(49);
  sheet.hideColumns(50);
  sheet.hideColumns(51);
  sheet.hideColumns(52);
  sheet.hideColumns(53);
  sheet.hideColumns(54);
  sheet.hideColumns(55);
  sheet.hideColumns(56);
  sheet.hideColumns(57);
  sheet.hideColumns(58);
  sheet.hideColumns(59);
  sheet.hideColumns(60);
  sheet.hideColumns(61);
  sheet.hideColumns(62);
  sheet.hideColumns(63);
  sheet.hideColumns(64);
  sheet.hideColumns(65);
  sheet.hideColumns(66);
  sheet.hideColumns(67);
  sheet.hideColumns(68);
  sheet.hideColumns(69);
  sheet.hideColumns(70);
  sheet.hideColumns(71);
  sheet.hideColumns(72);
  sheet.hideColumns(73);
  sheet.hideColumns(74);
  sheet.hideColumns(75);
  sheet.hideColumns(76);
  sheet.hideColumns(77);
  sheet.hideColumns(78);
  sheet.hideColumns(79);
  sheet.hideColumns(80);
  sheet.hideColumns(81);
  sheet.hideColumns(82);
  sheet.hideColumns(83);
  sheet.hideColumns(84);
  sheet.hideColumns(85);
  sheet.hideColumns(86);
  sheet.hideColumns(87);
  sheet.hideColumns(88);
  sheet.hideColumns(89);
  sheet.hideColumns(90);
  sheet.hideColumns(91);
  sheet.hideColumns(92);
}
```

[image: Product Tool Demo]
[image: Product Tool Demo Controls]